# Aggregate data by order of magnitude in R

Tags: r, aggregate

Suppose this data set:

```
df = data.frame(city=c(A,A,A,B,B,C,C,C,C), party=c(D,R,I,D,R,D,R,I,U), votes=c(10,2,9,7,2,1,7,3,8))
```

I want to calculate the difference in votes between the most and the second most voted parties for each city. But each city has more than two parties. The result I want would be:

```
city vote.diff
 A       1
 B       5
 C       1
```

Any help?

Comment: I fear that you do not yet understand that there is a huge difference between "A" ... the letter-A, and `A` the token/name of an object for which the R evaluation system will go looking for a value which n=might or might not be "A".

Comment: I don't that's the right term: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/order_of_magnitude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dataframe used for testing. Modeled after the psuedo-code above:

```
df = data.frame(city=c('A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C','C'), 
                party=c('D','R','I','D','R','D','R','I','U'), 
                votes=c(10,2,9,7,2,1,7,3,8))
```

The code:

```
resV <- lapply(split(df, df$city), function(df.x){
                      res <- xtabs(votes~party, data=df.x); 
                     -diff( res[ order(res,decreasing=TRUE) ][1:2]) } )
data.frame(city=names(resV), 
           vote.diff=unlist(resV), 
            winner=names(unlist(resV)) )

    city vote.diff winner
A.I    A         1    A.I
B.R    B         5    B.R
C.R    C         1    C.R
```

If you want to leave out the winner column it should be a trivial fix.